# Search string for first char different than "X"

Tags: c++, stdstring

The opposite of str.find('X') -
What is the most efficient way of finding first character in std::string that is different than specific char? If I have a string that consists of mainly X'es, but at some point there is another char - how do I find it quickly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::string str = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXX";

size_t index = str.find_first_not_of('X');
```

But a plain old for loop will be just as good.

Or, if you want an iterator instead of an index, perhaps like this:

```
std::string::iterator = std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
                        [](char c){ return c != 'X'; });
```

Comment: @dribeas There's an overload that takes a single char, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient way would be to iterate through the string and compare each character with `'X'`, returning the first one that is different.

Without any prior knowledge about the string, I don't see an approach better than `O(n)`, and calling `find('X')` succesively might be worse than just iterating through the characters.